# PHP SQL Server get error message on execute

Tags: php, sql-server

I am lost a bit, shifting from regular queries to parametrized and it seems I cannot get an error.
I know for sure sql does not perform INSERT but also there is no error displayed.
How do I see errors with execute statements? The actual query has 50 values. Below is a code smaple, I just need ot know how to pull errors on execute. Thank you!

```
$sqlParamsArUpd = array('10', '20')
$data = $conn->prepare($sqlNew);
$data->execute($sqlParamsArUpd);
if ($data) { 
     // code continues here (SQL does not insert values and code simply continues here, instead of showing error
} else {
     print_r($conn->errorInfo())
}
```

Comment: Your code is very minimal, but I guess that `$data->execute()` will return `FALSE` when the query fails. Note that this boolean is not `$data`, which is your prepared statement object.

Comment: Ah, I think that `$conn->errorInfo()` gives away that you're using PDO, so it is possible that you're actually trying to access a Microsoft SQL server.

Comment: If this is PDO, then you can set an attribute to enable it to throw exceptions whenever a problem occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the boolean from [PDOStatement::execute](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

```
$sqlParamsArUpd = array('10', '20')
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlNew);
$inserted = $stmt->execute($sqlParamsArUpd); // Returns true or false
if ($inserted) { 
      echo $stmt->rowCount()." rows inserted";
} else {
     print_r($stmt->errorInfo()) 
}
```